# If a point P is in the line of two positive charges, does it experience the electric field of the inner positive charge?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

If a point P is in the line of two positive charges, does it experience the electric fields of the inner positive charge? Wouldn't the one of the positive charge's electric field be blocking the way? How does P get the other Q's electric field. According to the diagram, the leftmost Q's electric field is cancelled by the right Q's electric field in the middle and the right most Q's electric field seems to shield point P from the left most Q's electric field resulting in no electric field felt at point P by the left most +Q

The only way for point P to feel left Q's electric field is if left Q's electric field went through right Q's electric field and the drawing is just the net electric field not representative of the actual electric field going on

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electric fields are linear, which means that the combination of individual ones is simply the sum of the individual ones. Electric fields can cancel each other out if they are of equal magnitude and opposite sign, but they don't "block" each other. They pass right through each other.

Comment: I updated with more details. With the picture of the electric field it seems like the other Q's electric field is blocked.

Comment: @Anna The lines are just to help visualize the field and help represent the math. The don’t block anything. The value of the files at point p would be the sum of the field from the two charges. The lines that are drawn should represent the sum of the field of the two charges.

Comment: Ok, what if instead of the two charges, there were two infinitely large oppositely charged plates. Would the electric field of one plate block the other?